# React Text Resize stored in localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a React Component to increase and decrease font size.
Values a stored in localStorage. Everything seems working ok, but i can't value on the begining i try few options but without success.

Everything is defined in props there is no errors i cant get font size value

Here is my project on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/textsizer-n3m3c

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TextResizer = ({
  defaultFont,
  step,
  min,
  max,
  suffix,
  store,
  storeKey
}) => {
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(defaultFont);

  const getTextSize = useCallback(() => {
    let fontSize;
    if (store && store.getItem(storeKey)) {
      fontSize = setFontSize({ fontSize: store.getItem(storeKey) });
    } else {
      fontSize = setFontSize({ fontSize: fontSize });
    }
    return parseInt(fontSize, 10);
  }, [store, storeKey]);

  const toggle = (type) => {
    let newFontSize = getTextSize();
    switch (type) {
      case "increase":
        newFontSize += step;
        break;
      case "decrease":
        newFontSize -= step;
        break;
      default:
        newFontSize = defaultFont;
        break;
    }
    setFontSize({ fontSize: newFontSize });
    store.setItem(storeKey, newFontSize);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getTextSize();
    if (store && store.getItem(storeKey)) {
      setFontSize({ fontSize: store.getItem(storeKey) });
    }
    
  }, [getTextSize, store, storeKey]);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button disabled={fontSize <= min} onClick={() => toggle("decrease")}>
       decrease
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => toggle("default")}>default</button>
      <button disabled={fontSize >= max} onClick={() => toggle("increase")}>
        increase
      </button>
      <style>{`html { font-size: ${fontSize}${suffix} }`.trim()}</style>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
TextResizer.propTypes = {
  defaultFont: PropTypes.number,
  step: PropTypes.number,
  min: PropTypes.number,
  max: PropTypes.number,
  suffix: PropTypes.string,
  store: PropTypes.object,
  storeKey: PropTypes.string
};
TextResizer.defaultProps = {
  defaultFont: 100,
  step: 20,
  min: 60,
  max: 180,
  suffix: "%",
  store: localStorage,
  storeKey: "TextResizer"
};
export default TextResizer;
```

Comment: Why no props passed to <TextResizer /> ? I can see several props needed for this component.

Comment: I've everything in my default props. I don't need to pass any arguments

Comment: @DigitalLegend could you explain the issue?

Comment: I cant get value of the "fontSize" when im rendering components, everything else working as should be. I get [object Object]

Comment: You were expecting fontSize to be a number but in between you changed it to an object. like {fontsize:fontsize}

Comment: More problems on getTextSize(); You are assigning the same state value to its setState call and making it undefined. I didn't completely fixed your issue but fixed main blunders, https://codesandbox.io/s/textsizer-forked-i2hb5?file=/src/components/TextResizer.js

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues, you're setting the `fontSize` to an object. You don't need the `getTextSize` function. In the `useEffect` you can check if the stored font size is truthy and an integer before updating the state.

Here's the updated sandbox:

[image: Edit TextSizer (forked)]

```
  const toggle = (type) => {
    let newFontSize = fontSize;
    switch (type) {
      case "increase":
        newFontSize += step;
        break;
      case "decrease":
        newFontSize -= step;
        break;
      default:
        newFontSize = defaultFont;
        break;
    }
    setFontSize(newFontSize);
    store.setItem(storeKey, newFontSize);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedValue = store.getItem(storeKey);
    if (storedValue) {
      const size = +storedValue;
      if (Number.isSafeInteger(size)) {
        setFontSize(size);
      }
    }
  }, [store, storeKey]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {fontSize}
      <button disabled={fontSize <= min} onClick={() => toggle("decrease")}>
        decrease
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => toggle("default")}>default</button>
      <button disabled={fontSize >= max} onClick={() => toggle("increase")}>
        increase
      </button>
      <style>{`html { font-size: ${fontSize}${suffix} }`.trim()}</style>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```